# getting domain names of user created domain classes in Grails

Tags: grails

Is there a way to access domain objects metadata of only the domain created by the user (for lack of a better word) as opposed to domain objects that are part are integrated into a project by means of plugins, etc?

What I'm after is getting names of domain objects in gsp file for all sorts of gui related activities ( building menus, etc.)

So if I do something like this:

```
<%
    for( domain in grailsApplication.domainClasses ){
        print ( '<h3>domain class locgial property name: ' + domain.logicalPropertyName + '</h3>' )
        print ( '<h3>domain  full name: ' + domain.fullName + '</h3>' )
    }
%>
```

... I can get the names, hack them in JS to determined if they belong my own generated packages ( com.ra for instance ), but that seems very fragile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin classes have the `org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.metadata.GrailsPlugin` annotation added to them by the compiler, so you can pass down just the application's domain classes from the controller to the GSP in the model like this:

```
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.metadata.GrailsPlugin

class MyController {

   def myAction = {
      ...
      def appDomainClasses = grailsApplication.domainClasses.findAll {
         !it.clazz.isAnnotationPresent(GrailsPlugin)
      }
      [appDomainClasses: appDomainClasses]
   }
}
```

and then loop through them in the GSP:

```
<g:each var='dc' in='${appDomainClasses}'>
<h3>domain class logical property name: ${dc.logicalPropertyName}</h3>
<h3>domain full name: ${dc.fullName}</h3>
</g:each>
```

Answer (score 2):

In **Grails 3.3.11** I was able to find the list of **domain classes** as below.

```
List<GrailsClass> getDomainClasses() {
    Holders.grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain").findAll {
        it.pluginName == null
    }.toList()
}
```

To find the list of **controller classes** the following method might be helpful.

```
List<GrailsClass> getControllerClasses() {
    Holders.grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Controller").findAll {
        it.pluginName == null
    }.toList()
}
```

To get only the **names of user-created domain classes** use the below code.

```
List<String> getDomainClassesNames() {
    Holders.grailsApplication.getArtefacts("Domain").findAll {
        it.pluginName == null
    }.collect {it.shortName }.toList()
}
```

To play with the properties of domain class you can think of using the below code

```
List<MetaProperty> findDomainClassProperties(GrailsClass domainClass) {
    return domainClass.metaClass.properties
}
```